# Getting all references to a view on BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to optimize the queries I have in a BigQuery project.

Unhopefully, the code wasn't archived into a source control solution like Git.

Is there a way to construct a diagram of dependencies between all the tables and views?
Or at least, given a view or a table, list views and scheduled queries having a reference to it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

List of BigQuery views containing a specific table name in the `view_definition` can be queried from [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-views):

```
SELECT *
FROM region-us.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS
WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(view_definition, 'your_dataset_name.your_table_name')

-- Update: added dataset-wise if region-wise is not available (kudos to Michel)
SELECT *
FROM your_dataset_name.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS
WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(view_definition, 'your_dataset_name.your_table_name')
```

List of BigQuery scheduled queries with their definitions can be downloaded with [bq or API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/working-with-transfers#listing_transfers) and then can be searched for `your_dataset_name.your_table_name` (for example with [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)):

```
bq ls --transfer_config --transfer_location=US --format=prettyjson | jq '.[] | select(.params.query|test("your_dataset_name.your_table_name"))'
```

Comment: `region-us.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS` has to be fixed I replaced it with a valid dataset name, but I get the idea thank you.

Comment: I get a partial response with `jq: error (at <stdin>:405): null (null) cannot be matched, as it is not a string`

Comment: hmm... could you try this?
`bq ls --transfer_config --transfer_location=US --format=prettyjson | jq '.[] | select(.params.query != null) | select(.params.query|test("requests.events"))'`

Comment: Don't worry the question wasn't about using `jq`, it may be clear to just provide an answer with `--format=prettyjson` and then do what every you like with your text editor.

Thanks again, it was really helpful!

Comment: I recommend using `gron` instead of / complementary to `jq`, it is less error prone: https://github.com/tomnomnom/gron